# How to add title of the plot in Chartist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plot, charts, title

I use 'react-chartist'. I want to add the title of the plot, this is not working for me:

```
const options = {
  title:{
    display:true,
    text: 'Some name'
  }
}
<ChartistGraph
          className='ct-hidden-points-title'
          data={data}
          options={options}
          type='Line'
         
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a title property for an entire graph.

There is a plugin for axis titles (https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/plugins.html#axis-title-plugin), but from the question that doesn't seem like what you're looking for.

if you only want to show some text under or above the graph you can just put it there and add style `textAlign: 'center'` to the parent element:

```
// ...
<div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
  <h1>Chart title</h1>
  <ChartistGraph
    className="ct-hidden-points-title"
    data={data}
    options={options}
    type={type}
  />
</div>
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you, but i use 'react-chartjs-2' now, it support the option of the title and legend.